# undefined url dropdown change based on another

Tags: jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

Iam working on asp.net core project, am facing minor problem on  populating districts based on region. when i select a region  i get undefined url.

```
<select id="Select_District"
    data_url ="@Url.Action("GetDistricts")"
    asp-for="DistrictId"
    asp-items="@Model.Districts"
    class="" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="">Please select one</option>
</select>
<label>District</label>
```

Dropdown change event

```
$("#Select_Region").change(function () {
$("#Select_District").removeAttr("disabled");
var v = $(this).val();
var url = $("#Select_District").data("url") + '?u=' + v;
var $fac= $("#Select_District");
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    $fac.empty();
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        $fac.append($("<option>").text(item.Text).val(item.Value));
    });
});
```

Comment: It looks you are having typo
`data_urli ="@Url.Action("GetDistricts")` it should be `data-url ="@Url.Action("GetDistricts")`

Comment: I changed it but not working thanks

Comment: also remove '_' with '-'

Comment: With '-'  the district isn't populating now. I had put demo data in it and can see when i type in browser

Comment: you need to compare both url which you typed in browser which is working fine with the data-url getting set in district dropdown. Try to `inspect element` to use 'console.log' or 'alert'